# reading .csv file with decimals separated by a comma with CSV.jl

Tags: csv, dataframe, julia

I am trying to read some data into julia into a data frame to work with it. A minimal example of the .csv file could look like this:

```
A; B; C; D
ab; 1,23; 4; 9,2
ab; 3,4; 7; 1,1
ba; 6; 2,3; 8,6
```

I load the following to packages and read the data:

```
using DataFrames
using CSV
d = CSV.read( "test.csv", delim=";")
```

Julia recognizes the following types:

```
eltypes(d)

CategoricalArrays.CategoricalString{UInt32}
String
String
String
```

How could I now turn whole columns to floats with the comma replaced by a dot? My first idea was to use:

```
float(d[1,2])
```

But I did not find an option to tell julia to replace the comma with a dot.
My next idea was to first replace the comma and then convert it:

```
float(replace(d[1,2], ",", "."))
```

That works fine on a single cell but not on a whole column:

```
float(replace(d[:,2], ",", "."))
MethodError: no method matching 
replace(::WeakRefStrings.WeakRefStringArray{WeakRefString{UInt8},1,Union{}}, 
::String, ::String)
```

I also tried:

```
d = CSV.read( "test.csv", delim=";", decimal=",")
```

which also just gives an error ...

Any ideas how to handle this problem and how to efficiently read the data into julia?

Thanks a lot!

Best regards.

Comment: Note that `float(replace(d[:,2], ",", "."))` should probably be `float.(replace.(d[:,2], ",", "."))` (broadcast operations).

Comment: You might also wanna have a look at [ReadWriteDlm2.jl](https://github.com/strickek/ReadWriteDlm2.jl), particular it's `readdlm2()` method.

Comment: Also, technically your input file isn't a csv file (the data isn't comma separated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One straightforward way is to read the file to string, replace the comma decimal separators by dots and then create the DataFrame from it:

```
s = replace(readstring("test.csv"), ",", ".")
CSV.read(IOBuffer(s); delim=';', types=[String, Float64, Float64, Float64])
```

Note that you can use the `types` keyword to specifiy the column types (it will then implicitly parse the string entries).

**EDIT**: According to [this github issue](https://github.com/JuliaData/CSV.jl/issues/83) the CSV.jl's `read` method supports a `decimal` keyword (from version v0.2.0 on) which allows you to do

`CSV.read("test.csv"; delim=';', decimal=',', types=[String, Float64, Float64, Float64])`

**EDIT**: Removed hint to alternatively use `readtable` from DataFrames.jl because it seems to be deprecated in favor of `CSV.read`.

Comment: First argument of `CSV.read()` is either a `String`, the file path, or an `IO` object.

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly! Found the answer to my previous question already myself in the help ...

Comment: With using `readtable` as suggested I get two error messages: `readtable is deprecated, use CSV.read from the CSV package instead` and `ArgumentError: Argument 'decimal' is not yet supported.` `CSV.read` should also support `decimal`, but for me it does not work. Also for a dataset with more columns its quite cumbersome to specify the types of all columns ...

Comment: Didn't know about the deprecation. Removed respective reference in answer. Check version of your CSV package with `Pkg.status("CSV")`. You have to have at least `v0.2.0` for the `decimal` keyword.

Comment: Thanks. It now works ... I always had a comma behind the file name and not a semicolon.

Comment: By the way: one other question as I just noticed a difference in the behavior and I always thought that they behave exactly the same. When to use `' '` and when `" "`. What is the difference in the behavior?

Comment: `typeof` is your friend. `'c'` is a `Char` while `"c"` is a `String`